# IIS 7.5 / Windows 7: Error 500.19, error code 0x800700b7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, 500-error, 500

I have been trying to resolve this issue.

I am using Windows 7 and VS2008 +iis7.5. My project is stuck because of this error.

The error says:

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
`Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x800700b7
Config Error    There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test23\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/test23
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test23
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
Config Source
   15:         <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   16:          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
   17:           <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
`
```

I followed the instructions in this Microsoft solution document, but it didn't help.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating that the scriptResourceHandler is being defined twice. The key isn't the 500.19 (something bad happened in the configuration), it's the text of the error.

It's quite [common](http://forums.asp.net/p/1398360/3015963.aspx) to [hit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/bb9bde04-b6a9-4e4f-b657-d9073ff2fd56) [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1149226.aspx) with the scriptResourceHandler.

In short: remove it from the app's web.config and it should work. Alternatively, add a  or  entry for it in the web.config, then re-add it.

It's probably defined higher up in the configuration hierarchy somewhere.